# Recursive function returns 0 when its done. Why doesn't 'return 0' override the previous return value of the function?

Tags: python

The function finds the sum of the items in a list and works fine. It adds the first item on list with the remainder of the list. 
Calls the function *mysum* recursively till it's empty.
When the list is empty, it returns 0. But why doesn't that override the previous return value of the function?

```
>>> def mysum(L):
       if not L:
           return 0
       else:
           return L[0] + mysum(L[1:]) 

>>> mysum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
15
```

Comment: the function is called once per element in the list, and retrieve the results reverssed. check how recursion works, only in the las call when the list is empty it will return 0 so `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +0`

Comment: I understand now. I misconceived what the `return 0` was doing. I thought it was assigning 0 to the value of the function in the end. But apparently that's not what happens. Thank you @Netwave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first call of the function is the last one that returns. Assume you have the list `[1,2,3]`. You code will end up with

```
return 1 + sum([2, 3])
```

In which `1 + sum([2,3])` is an *expression*. Until this expression becomes a value, the code waits there. So, it keeps this function open and waits for the result of `sum(2,3])`. Essentially, you code becomes

```
return 1 + (return 2 + sum([3]))
```

Again, the `2 + sum([3])` needs to wait for `sum([3])`, and you end up with something like

```
return 1 + (return 2 + (return 3 + sum([])))
```

Now, the `sum([])` doesn't have to wait for anyone, it becomes `0`, so

```
return 1 + (return 2 + (return 3 + 0))
return 1 + (return 2 + 3)
return 1 + 5
return 6
```

Comment: Clear and concise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the recursive call is not just passed down the call stack (e.g. `return mysum(L[1:])`), but processed at each intermediate step:

```
def mysum(L):
    if not L:
        return 0  # -------+
    else:  #               |       
        return L[0] + mysum(L[1:]) 
        #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ == 0  for the innermost call
        #      ^^^^^               != 0  in the general case
        #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ != 0  hence
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. mysum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`L` is not empty, so we go to the else:

```
2. return 1 + mysum([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`L` is not empty, so we go to the else:

```
3. return 2 + mysum([3, 4, 5])
```

`L` is not empty, so we go to the else:

```
4. return 3 + mysum([4, 5])
```

`L` is not empty, so we go to the else:

```
5. return 4 + mysum([5])
```

`L` is not empty, so we go to the else:

```
6. return 5 + mysum([])
```

`L` *is* empty, so we don't go to the else:

```
7. return 0
```

Now that we know the value of `mysum([])`, let's see what the value of 6. is:

```
6'. return 5 + 0
```

This is 5. Now that we know the value of `mysum([5])`, let's see what the value of 5. is:

```
5'. return 4 + 5
```

This is 9. Now that we know the value of `mysum([4, 5])`, let's see what the value of 4. is:

```
4'. return 3 + 9
```

This is 12. Now that we know the value of `mysum([3, 4, 5])`, let's see what the value of 3. is:

```
3'. return 2 + 12
```

This is 14. Now that we know the value of `mysum([2, 3, 4, 5])`, let's see what the value of 2. is:

```
2'. return 1 + 14
```

Now we know the value of `mysum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`: 15.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is nothing special. You're returning the result of `L[0]` plus the result of some function call. Image that "some function call" is a call to any other function:

```
else:
    return L[0] + sum(L[1:])
```

Would you expect that to override the return somehow? Of course not. It doesn't make a difference that it's `mysum` instead of `sum` here.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of a recursive fonction can be represent as a tree of calls. And calls are done before 'returns'.

So, in your example :

Calling mysum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) does :

step 1 - returns  1 + calls mysum([2, 3, 4, 5])

step 2 - the latter call returns 2 + calls mysum([3, 4, 5])

step 3 - the latter call returns 3 + calls mysum([4, 5])

step 4 - the latter call returns 4 + calls mysum([5])

step 5 - the latter call returns 5 + calls mysum([])

step 6 - the latter call returns 0

step 7 - It's going up the tree of calls and makes the adds.